# problems at splitting strings in java

Tags: java, string

I'm new to java and I want to know how to splits strings with values.

I had an array like this :

```
String[] CITIES = { 
        "Vancouver 94.0 15.0",
        "Seattle 88.0 52.0",
        "Portland 74.0 88.0",
        "San Francisco 42.0 241.0",
        "Los Angeles 89.0 338.0",
        "Las Vegas 153.0 302.0",
        "Calgary 259.0 15.0",
        "Salt Lake City 224.0 216.0",
        "Phoenix 192.0 348.0",
        "Helena 247.0 90.0"}
```

and I want to divide each string into 3 values, the name (String) the `x-value (double)`, and the `y-value (double)`

firstly I thought of cutting at every space, but for the cities like San Francisco, it won't work :(
any ideas?

Comment: regex with capturing groups

Comment: Well, you could use the last and the penultimate space to extract the values.

Comment: I think your input format is badly defined, if it doesn't have a clear separator defined.
Respectively doesn't have any rules for how to escape the separator in values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this assignment was meant for the OP to learn about the `lastIndexOf` and `substring` methods of the `String` class.

Here are the test results from one of my many tests.

```
City [name=Vancouver, latitude=94.0, longitude=15.0]
City [name=Seattle, latitude=88.0, longitude=52.0]
City [name=Portland, latitude=74.0, longitude=88.0]
City [name=San Francisco, latitude=42.0, longitude=241.0]
City [name=Los Angeles, latitude=89.0, longitude=338.0]
City [name=Las Vegas, latitude=153.0, longitude=302.0]
City [name=Calgary, latitude=259.0, longitude=15.0]
City [name=Salt Lake City, latitude=224.0, longitude=216.0]
City [name=Phoenix, latitude=192.0, longitude=348.0]
City [name=Helena, latitude=247.0, longitude=90.0]
```

Here's the complete runnable code.  The `parseCities` method finds the position of the last two spaces and uses `substring` to "split" the `String` into three pieces.

```
public class SplitCities {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] cities = { 
                "Vancouver 94.0 15.0",
                "Seattle 88.0 52.0",
                "Portland 74.0 88.0",
                "San Francisco 42.0 241.0",
                "Los Angeles 89.0 338.0",
                "Las Vegas 153.0 302.0",
                "Calgary 259.0 15.0",
                "Salt Lake City 224.0 216.0",
                "Phoenix 192.0 348.0",
                "Helena 247.0 90.0" };
        
        SplitCities sc = new SplitCities();
        City[] parsedCities = sc.parseCities(cities);
        
        for (int index = 0; index < parsedCities.length; index++) {
            System.out.println(parsedCities[index]);
        }
    }
    
    public City[] parseCities(String[] cities) {
        City[] parsedCities = new City[cities.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < cities.length; index++) {
            String line = cities[index];
            int longitudePosition = line.lastIndexOf(' ');
            int latitudePosition = line.lastIndexOf(' ', longitudePosition - 1);
            String name = line.substring(0, latitudePosition);
            double latitude = Double.valueOf(line.substring(
                    latitudePosition + 1, longitudePosition));
            double longitude = Double.valueOf(line.substring(longitudePosition));
            parsedCities[index] = new City(name, latitude, longitude);
        }
        
        return parsedCities;
    }
    
    public class City {
        
        private final double latitude, longitude;
        
        private final String name;

        public City(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {
            this.name = name;
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("City [name=");
            builder.append(name);
            builder.append(", latitude=");
            builder.append(latitude);
            builder.append(", longitude=");
            builder.append(longitude);
            builder.append("]");
            return builder.toString();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: it's perfect, it's effectively for an exercice and I think this is the method we have to have to use. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(.*) +([0-9.]+) +([0-9.]+)$");
for(String city: CITIES) {
    Matcher mx = regex.matcher(city);
    if(mx.find())
        System.out.printf("City: %s, Lat: %s, Lon: %s%n", mx.group(1), mx.group(2), mx.group(3));
}
```

with output

```
City: Vancouver, Lat: 94.0, Lon: 15.0
City: Seattle, Lat: 88.0, Lon: 52.0
City: Portland, Lat: 74.0, Lon: 88.0
City: San Francisco, Lat: 42.0, Lon: 241.0
City: Los Angeles, Lat: 89.0, Lon: 338.0
City: Las Vegas, Lat: 153.0, Lon: 302.0
City: Calgary, Lat: 259.0, Lon: 15.0
City: Salt Lake City, Lat: 224.0, Lon: 216.0
City: Phoenix, Lat: 192.0, Lon: 348.0
City: Helena, Lat: 247.0, Lon: 90.0
```

(note: to convert strings to numbers use e.g. `Double::parseDouble`)

Answer (score -2):

You could define a regex to parse out the string and two doubles, and split each string using the `split` method defined here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html